# Regular expression to capture a date

Tags: regex

What regular expressions would you use to extract all the dates in this folowing text and then put them into the following format YYYY-MM-DD?

So far I've come up with the following to match all the dates

```
\d{1,2}[\.\/-]\d{1,2}[\.\/-]\d{4}|\d{1}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{1}\/\d{2}\, \d{4}|\d{1}\.\d{2}\, \d{4}
```

But it just seem way too clumpsy!

Data:

```
Juan Ponce de León sights Florida for the first time, on 3.27, 1513
Giovanni da Verrazzano explored the Atlantic coast of North America under French employ, on 4.17.1524
The Roanoke Colony was found deserted, on 8/15/1590
John Smith founded the Jamestown settlement, on 5/14, 1607
The Dutch laid claim to the territories of New Netherland, on 11.11.1614
The Massachusetts Bay Colony founded, on 3-4-1629
```

I'm learning regular expressions, but I find it so confusing.

Comment: fwiw, this is a troublesome and open-ended problem [to quote XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1179/) _"ISO 8601 was published on 06/05/88 and most recently amended on 12/01/04."_, and depends a lot on context (ie. despite the document being written in English, is it from America or translated from French?) .. does the content contain _a literal quotation expressing another date format?_ (beware!) .. realistically, it's not a good fit for a single regular expression, but a dedicated library with a suite of logic (some of which may be regular expressions) and perhaps ways to hint at the source format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of getting the dates in the snippet of text, would be to use this.

```
(\d{1,2}[-\/\.,]){1,2}\s?\d{2,4}
```

- This takes, 1 to 2 digits `\d{1,2}`
- Then it looks for a delimiter, `[-\/\.,]`
- it then repeats the first two steps 1 to 2 times. `(...){1,2}` could be a date with 01,2002 that would also be caught. otherwise just make it `{2}`
- Then it looks for a potential whitespace character between the date and the year. `\s?`
- And at last it looks for a year `\d{2,4}`

The solution can be seen here on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZcHa3t/1).

---

Date specific regex.

If you want a regex that are a bit more stable in getting the correct dates, then you could do something like this.

```
[^2-9](0?[0-9]|1[0-2])[-\/\.,]([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])[-\/\.,]\s?\d{2,4}
```

This regex does some checking to see if the date follows the mm-dd-yyyy format. It checks if the `mm < 12` and that `dd < 31`
Format checking date regex can be seen at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Xxy3aX/5)

Answer (score 3):

I would not rely entirely on regular expressions for this.  I would pick out the dates like so and then apply an instance of [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to each one to see if one of them matches. You can also use that formatter to reformat it to your requirements. Here is the first part.  Only works for numeric values as per your examples.

```
String s = """
Juan Ponce de León sights Florida for the first time, on 3.27, 1513
Giovanni da Verrazzano explored the Atlantic coast of North America under French employ, on 4.17.1524
The Roanoke Colony was found deserted, on 8/15/1590
John Smith founded the Jamestown settlement, on 5/14, 1607
The Dutch laid claim to the territories of New Netherland, on 11.11.1614
The Massachusetts Bay Colony founded, on 3-4-1629
        """;

String possibleDate = "(\\d+[-,\\s.]+\\d+[-,\\s.]+\\d+)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(possibleDate).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

prints

```
3.27, 1513
4.17.1524
11.11.1614
3-4-1629
```

But what about dates like `1-2-2022`?  Is that `January 2nd` or `February 1st`?  And don't forget about Locales which can also have different formats.

Also, if I were writing an app that required a date I would specify a particular acceptable format.

Comment: Defining a bunch of `DateTimeFormatter`s and attempting to parse matching strings, as you've mentioned, would be the most reliable approach since it's inherently impossible to make sure that a string represents a `100%`-valid date using regex only. Although, it would also require dealing with `DateTimeParseException`.

Answer (score 1):

This regex `[[:digit:]]{1,2}[.\/-][[:digit:]]{1,2}([.-\/]|, )[[:digit:]]{4}` will match all the dates, but note that it does not attempt to make sure the month or day numbers are actually valid i.e. `14.68.1990` would match even though that isn't a valid date on the Gregorian calendar. When attempting to replace each date in the original string, you would probably want some logic to ensure that the matched 'date' is actually a valid date.